# Keeping power on a capacitor after its charged?

Tags: capacitor

I am building a capacitor bank. I have them soldered in already. My question is simple-ish:

Can I keep the power on while one capacitor is done charging? Like If i hold the charge button on for 10 seconds will it hurt the capacitor. Even if It is a slow possess but in the long run yes, I need to know.

Comment: What are you charging it with?

Comment: 10v dc power supply with switch

Comment: I realize this was not your question, but you might want to add a resistor to that situation.

Comment: Ok Thx I'll do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are charging it with a voltage source and I further assume that you are obeying the voltage rating of the capacitor.

Under these assumptions, you are not damaging the capacitor by leaving it attached to a voltage source.

Comment: Will mark as best Awnser when I am able too.